# Angular http post how to attach file and data

Tags: angular, http

I have a database (MongoDB), a server (made with Node - using Express) and a client (made with Angular).
I want my client to be able to upload a file and text (JSON) to the node-server, which then stores the data in the database.

I used Postman to send an image and the data - to make sure that the server was set up correctly. (See the screenshot)

[image: Postman settings with dummy data]

Sending data using Postman like this works. Now I want to make my Angular client do the same thing. Below is the code I'm using. It's a bit of a mess right now, because I have tried lots of different things.

```
sendToServer(url){
    let inputField_Image = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("inputField_image");
    let inputField_Raw = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("inputField_raw");
    let image = inputField_Image.value;
    let raw = inputField_Raw.value;
    let data = JSON.parse(raw);

    let formData: FormData = new FormData();

    formData.append('image', image);

    formData.append('name', data.name);
    formData.append('cost', data.cost);
    formData.append('type', data.type);
    formData.append('subType', data.subType);
    formData.append('text', data.text);
    formData.append('flavor', data.flavor);
    formData.append('power', data.power);
    formData.append('toughness', data.toughness);

    let options = { content: formData };

    //let x = JSON.stringify(formData);

    //console.log(x);

    this.http.post(url, options).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log('response:', res);
    });

}
```

When I run this code with the same dummy data in the client - I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined" - as if no data were received by the server at all.

Below is the code from my node server:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const PASSWORD = "admin";
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

//other code..

router.post('/image', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
    let imgPath = path.join(__dirname, '../') + req.file.path;
    let imgAsBase64 = base64_encode(imgPath);
    let newCard = req.body;
    newCard.image = imgAsBase64;

    Card.create(newCard).then(function(card){
        console.log('\nThe following Schema was successfully saved to Mongodb:');
        console.log(card.name);
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log('\nTrying to save a Schema Mongodb, error: \n', error);
    });

    res.send('Successfully uploaded card!');
});

//other code..
```

The server-side code works with Postman, so I think my error is in the client.
How can I send an image file (uploaded using the `<input type="file">` element) along with data (uploaded using the `<textarea>` element)?

EDIT: I added a `console.log(req.body);` in the server side - just to see what I recieve. And I got this: `{ content: {} }` no idea why...

Comment: try move `formData.append('image', image);` below the others `append`

Comment: I tried moving it below  the others, but got the same error message. It seems as though my FormData object is empty..